# How to find first occurrence of a vector of numeric elements within a data frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, subset

I have a data frame (min_set_obs) which contains two columns: the first containing numeric values, called treatment, and the second an id column called seq:

```
min_set_obs
 Treatment seq
       1   29
       1   23
       3   60
       1   6
       2   41
       1   5
       2   44
```

Let's say I have a vector of numeric values, called `key`:

```
key
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

I.e. a vector of three 1s, two 2s, and one 3.

How would I go about identifying which rows from my `min_set_obs` data frame contain the first occurrence of values from the `key` vector?

I'd like my output to look like this:

```
Treatment seq
   1   29
   1   23
   3   60
   1   6
   2   41
   2   44
```

I.e. the sixth row from `min_set_obs` was 'extra' (it was the fourth 1 when there should only be three 1s), so it would be removed.

I'm familiar with the `%in%` operator, but I don't think it can tell me the position of the first occurrence of the `key` vector in the first column of the `min_set_obs` data frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr`, you can firstly count the `keys` using `table` and then take the top n rows correspondingly from each group:

```
library(dplyr)
m <- table(key)

min_set_obs %>% group_by(Treatment) %>% do({
    # as.character(.$Treatment[1]) returns the treatment for the current group
    # use coalesce to get the default number of rows (0) if the treatment doesn't exist in key
    head(., coalesce(m[as.character(.$Treatment[1])], 0L))
})

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   Treatment [3]
#  Treatment   seq
#      <int> <int>
#1         1    29
#2         1    23
#3         1     6
#4         2    41
#5         2    44
#6         3    60
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `base R`, where we `split` the 'min_set_obs' by 'Treatment' into a `list`, get the `head` of elements in the `list` using the corresponding frequency of 'key' and `rbind` the `list` elements to a single `data.frame`

```
res <- do.call(rbind, Map(head, split(min_set_obs, min_set_obs$Treatment), n = table(key)))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#   Treatment seq
#1         1  29
#2         1  23   
#3         1   6
#4         2  41
#5         2  44
#6         3  60
```